# Nominal type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface A {}
interface B {}

let a: A;
let b: B;

// I want this to fail to compile
a = b;
```

Because interfaces `A` and `B` look the same it compiles just fine. How can I define variable `a` such that `a = b` fails to compile because the types are different?

Typescript 4.7.4.

Comment: TypeScript has a [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/structural-typing), which is why your example compiles just fine. To achieve what you want to do, you need something like [newtypes or tagged types](https://kubyshkin.name/posts/newtype-in-typescript/), which are not native to TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These interfaces (shapes) overlap, so even though a: A, it can still be assigned to b: B.

```
interface A {
    type: 'A'
}
interface B {
    type: 'B'
}

let a: A;
let b: B;

// fails
a = b;
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I came up with too. Was hoping I could do something like: `let a: A!` where when the compiler sees `!` ensures that it must be of compile-time-type `A`.

Comment: The structure type system makes it very flexible in TypeScript and you don't necessarily need type narrowing / type widening to achieve polymorphism